# Finding biggest value for key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to find out the largest country with greatest area.

my data set is as follows

```
Afghanistan 648
Albania 29
Algeria 2388
Andorra 0
Austria 84
Bahrain 1
Bangladesh  143
Belgium 31
Benin   113
Bhutan  47
Brunei  6
Bulgaria    111
Burma   678
Cameroon    474
Central-African-Republic    623
Chad    1284
China   9561
Cyprus  9
Czechoslovakia  128
Denmark 43
Djibouti    22
Egypt   1001
Equatorial-Guinea   28
Ethiopia    1222
Finland 337
France  547
Germany-DDR 108
Germany-FRG 249
Greece  132
Guam    0
Hong-Kong   1
Hungary 93
India   3268
```

Can anyone help me to write mapreduce programme?

My mapper and reducer code is this

Mapper

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
        if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) == 1){
            context.write(new Text(tokens[0]), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3])));
        }
    }
```

Reducer

```
public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int max = 0;
        for(IntWritable x : values){
            if(max < Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(x))){
                max = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));
    }
```

Comment: So what did you try and where are you stuck? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thanks for replying @ThomasJungblut , i have edited my question and added mapper and reducer code , i am somewhere lacking in implementing logic.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is easy, in the mapper you gather the max and at the end of your mapper you write it to disk using `cleanup`.

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
String token;

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
        if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) == 1){       
            int val = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3])
            if(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]) > max){
                max = val;
                token = tokens[0];
            }
        }
}

@Override
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    
    context.write(new LongWritable(max), new Text(token));    
}
```

All your stuff now get's reduced on the max, which means if we sort descending, you get the maximum as the first record in the reducer. Therefore you need to set this in your job:

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(LongWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);
```

The reducer is a simply found/not-found switch that just outputs every country if it has the maximum value (first record).

```
boolean foundMax = false;

@Override
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        if(!foundMax){
            for(Text t : values){
                context.write(t, key);
            }
            foundMax = true;
        }              
}
```

Comment: So @ThomasJunglblut we do not set the key and value in map and what is the role of cleanUp and when it called?

Comment: `Cleanup` is the final operation of a mapper.

Comment: Thanks bro , it is working... but i want to know we are not setting key values in context of mapper then how values are passing to reducer can you show me the architectural view in this particular case if it is easy to describe for you

Comment: because you are not setting stuff, you are writing to a stream. That's what `context.write(k,v)` does.

Comment: Hi @ThomasJunglblut this example is working without reducer why? do we need this reducer or not

Comment: You need a reducer only if you have >1 mapper task